# How to makemigrations django 2.2.9 multiple DB

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, makemigrations

So I am working in a legacy project with a Django 2.2.9 and here we have 3 DBs, nobody migrated on two additional databases ever, and now its time to do it, but nobody knows how to do it on django 2.2.9 on a database that is not default... I tried writing migration manually and running it - didnt help

python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

Any help?

Comment: Well I read the documentation before asking obviously, and tried using routers, but it didnt help, and its not clear how django will see my changes while running makemigrations even with routers (to me), probably I did something wrong : - (

Answer (score 0):

I had this under my model:
class Meta:
managed = False

only now after few hours understood that it was preventing makemigrations :)